# Просто не работает haml, ошибка

Tags: ruby, gems, windows-11, haml

Выполнил установку **Ruby с MYSYS2(MINGW64)** и установил **Haml Gem** командой **gem install haml.**
В папке проекта создал командой **bundle** Gemfile
прописав **'gem haml'** и завершив все инсталляцией зависимостей **bundle install** **для haml**

После команды **haml index.haml index.html**
вывод с ошибкой, что можно сделать?

```
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/haml-6.2.3/lib/haml/cli.rb:114:in `method_missing': undefined method `index.haml' for #<Haml::CLI:0x00000164de897eb8 @_invocations={Haml::CLI=>["index.haml"]}, @_initializer=[["index.html"], [], {:shell=>#<Thor::Shell::Basic:0x00000164de221bd8 @base=#<Haml::CLI:0x00000164de897eb8 ...>, @mute=false, @padding=0, @always_force=false>, :current_command=>#<struct Thor::DynamicCommand name="index.haml", description="A dynamically-generated command", long_description="index.haml", wrap_long_description=nil, usage="index.haml", options={}, options_relation={}, ancestor_name=nil>}], @options={"escape_html"=>true, "escape_attrs"=>true}, @args=["index.html"], @shell=#<Thor::Shell::Basic:0x00000164de221bd8 @base=#<Haml::CLI:0x00000164de897eb8 ...>, @mute=false, @padding=0, @always_force=false>> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/command.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/command.rb:144:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/base.rb:584:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/haml-6.2.3/exe/haml:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/haml:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/haml:32:in `<main>'
```

Comment: А что сделать хотели вообще?

Comment: Получить файл .html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по доке гема, команда должна выглядеть как

```
haml render index.haml
```

Больше информации выдаст `haml --help`

Comment: w3.org.ua/html/preprotsessor-haml Две разные команды эта создаёт файл. Судя по ошибке, сделал вывод что она была удалена. Пойдет haml render index.haml > index.html